# Cannot change superusers own django admin inline

Tags: django, django-admin

I have recently updated from django 2.0.4 to 3.0.5.

I have a UserAdmin with the following inline:

```
class PreferencesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Preferences
    can_delete = False
    classes = ['collapse']
```

When I login as a superuser, I can change the preferences of other users through the inline, but not my own. Why is that? On our server with django 2.0.4 I can both change other users preferences but also my own preferences through the inline. I could not find any explanation for this strange behaviour...

**EDIT** The same behaviour applies when I try to change my Preferences directly in the admin, so this is not specifically an issue with the inline.

**EDIT2** The problem is the following middleware. Any ideas how it could be modified to solve the problem?

```
class UserLanguageMiddleware:
    """ Middleware to set user language """
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user_language = request.user.profile.language
            activate(user_language)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Comment: What specifically are you seeing?

Comment: I get the default success message: 'The user “username” was changed successfully. You may edit it again below.' But changes to neither text inputs nor checkboxes of the inline are saved.

Comment: BTW: The changes do also show correctly in the change history, but are not getting saved. See also my EDIT above.

Comment: How do you know UserLanguageMiddleware is the problem?

Comment: By deactivating it, the problem was gone. By activating it again, the problem was back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the official Django advice to [explicity setting the active language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language), the problem was solved:

settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'language'
```

middleware.py:

```
class UserLanguageMiddleware:
    """ Middleware to set user language cookie """
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if request.user.is_authenticated and not request.COOKIES.get(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME):
            # Set cookie
            response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, request.user.profile.language)
        elif not request.user.is_authenticated and request.COOKIES.get(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME):
            # Delete cookie
            response.delete_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME)
        return response
```

models.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
# Update user language on login
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def post_login(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    user_language = user.profile.language
    translation.activate(user_language)
```